# How to test laptop adapter voltage with a Digital Voltage Detection Screwdriver Test Pen

Tags: laptop, voltage, ac-adapter

Couple of days ago I replaced my laptop adapter, and when I use that, some amount of current discharges through the sockets,ports...etc (i.e. audio out).
So I checked the adapter with a Test Pen (I don't have a Multimeter). When I connect to the charger outlet (-), Test Pen reads 110v.

Is this normal?

Thanks!

Comment: It appears that your adapter or the socket you are plugging it in is not properly grounded.

Comment: AC current is properly grounded. This happens only after adapter plugs to AC cable.

Comment: I don't know exactly a Test Pen is worth for testing a DC current.